# Tags unexpectedly switch on Libreoffice interaction when using "wmname LG3D"

Tags: java, awesome-wm

When using `wmname LG3D` (to fix a Java app display in awesome), hitting "File" in Libreoffice results in unexpected behavior: opposite display switches tags to match that of Libreoffice

(e.g., Libreoffice open in tag 5, display 2 ... hitting libreoffice-->"File" on display 2 results in display 1 snapping from tag 1 to tag 5 ... then when display 2 Libreoffice "File" is released left display tag will (sometimes) snap back to 1).

The snapping is a bit "jar"ring ... (sorry, couldn't resist) thanks for any suggestions.

Using 2 displays with nvidia-current inside ubuntu server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the relevant bug reports (this page links to more stuff): https://awesome.naquadah.org/bugs/index.php?do=details&task_id=852

Comment: thank Uli.  Understood it's an intentional Openoffice/(Libreoffice) behavior.  Were you ever able to ameliorate the issue?